# Presenting a navigation controller on a View Controller from storyboard

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard, swift2

In my app i have a storyboard which has initial view controller as X and then i have a navigation controller which has couple of view controllers attached with it through segue but there is no connection between ViewController x and this navigation controller.

Now based on a button tap in View controller x i want to present this navigation controller.

I am doing this :

```
func showDashBoard()
    {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let next = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navigation") as! EBNavigationController

        self.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

So the navigation view is getting presented with the root view controller but its not showing me animation and also i am getting a warning "Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
"
Can some one please help me in figuring out what is the best way to do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The animation problem can be fixed using `next.modalPresentationStyle` and `next.modalTransitionStyle`. Lookup the enums for the possible values and give it the one you want.
You usually get the "Attempt to present on whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" errors when you are calling this function before the view is fully loaded. For instance if you call it in the viewDidLoad method. You should call it only after viewDidAppear is called.